# How to take the continuum limit of an infinite sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinitesimals

This may be a trivial question for people dealing with infinite series a lot - but I am not and feel a bit insecure here.

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R; t\mapsto f(t)$. I am not sure if it matters, but we can consider it to be smooth ($\mathcal C^\infty$), and I am only interested in it on an interval $[t_*,\infty)$.

Now consider the infinite sequence $(t_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ with $t_i:=t_*+i\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. This then induces the infinite sequence $(f_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ with $f_i:=f(t_i)$.

I now want to take the continuum limit, i.e. I want to state that for arbitrarily small steps between the $t_i$, the series $(f_i)$ approaches the continuous function $f(t)$.

Intuitively that is clear to me, since it is in some sense by construction. What makes me cautious is, that if I take the limit $\epsilon\to0$, then $t_i\to t_*$ and $f_i\to f(t_*)$ for all $i$.

How do I get this straight?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when limits are taken in different orders.

The two limits are $\epsilon \to 0$
and $n \to \infty$
(the number of points).

What you have shown is that taking the limits in different orders produces different results.
This is not surprising.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @marty cohen ! But don't I have infinitely many point from the beginning? After all $(t_i)$ is an infinite sequence, since $\epsilon$ fits infinitely many times in the interval $[t_*,\infty)$. So do you suggest, I should define those sequences with a finite $n$ first, e.g. $(t_i)_{i=0}^n$, then take $\epsilon\to0$ and only then take $n\to\infty$? But wouldn't I then still face the same problem?

Comment: With limits you can always ignore the initial part. It's what happens eventually that matters.

Comment: Ok, but I am still confused. Did I now make a mistake in my formulation or not? Perhaps I should rephrase the question: Which limit(s) do I have to take an in what order, to end up with the continuum limit? Since naively taking $\epsilon\to0$ in the definition of $t_i$ does not seem to do the job. Sorry if I am slow on the uptake here.